# Get Data from Facebook Comment Plugin

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I learnt the way to build a comment plugin by copying the codes from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

I would like to know are there any ways to retrieve comments while users sending Facebook comments. i.e., send a comment to store in both Facebook database and my local database.

Answer (score 1):

After some reading at [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#faq), in the FAQ section:

**How do I know when someone commented on my site?**

You can subscribe to the 'comment.create' and 'comment.remove' events in the Facebook SDK for JavaScript through [FB.Event.subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.0#comments-example).

code:

```
// In your HTML, include the comments plugin
<div
  class="fb-comments"
  data-href="http://url.to.your-page/page.html"
  data-numposts="5"
  data-colorscheme="light">
</div>

// In your onload method
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', comment_callback);
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', comment_callback);

// In your JavaScript
var comment_callback = function(response) {
  console.log("comment_callback");
  console.log(response);
}
```